# Neither the property "dispositif" nor one of the methods

Tags: symfony

In a controller, I create a form:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$formProjetSearch = $this->createForm(EgwProjetSearchType::class, $em, [
    'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
]);
```

In my EgwProjetSearchType, I have:

```
$builder->add('dispositif', 'entity', array(
  'class'   => 'LeaPrestaBundle:EgwDispositif', 
  'property'  => 'nomDispositif',
  'label'   => 'nomDispositif',
  'required'  => true,
  'empty_value' => '',
  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) 
  {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
      ->where('d.isActive = :isActive')
      ->setParameter('isActive', 1)
      ->orderBy('d.nomDispositif','ASC');
  },
));
```

And I've got this error:

> Neither the property "dispositif" nor one of the methods "getDispositif()", "dispositif()", "isDispositif()", "hasDispositif()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".

Nonetheless, the entity exists:

```
<?php

namespace Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lea\PrestaBundle\Entity\EgwDispositif
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="egw_dispositif")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EgwDispositif
{
  /**
   * @var integer $idDispositif
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id_dispositif", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $idDispositif;

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EgwTypePrestation", inversedBy="dispositifs")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_type_prestation", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $idTypePrestation;
```

ETC ...

Thanks for your help !

Thakns for your messages, but, I just want to display in a form a entity in a listbox : i use the type EgwProjetSearchType, i add a field which is "dispositif" coming from entity EgwDispositif (which exists) and the return message is :

``` Neither the property "dispositif" nor one of the methods 
    "getDispositif()", "dispositif()", "isDispositif()", "hasDispositif()", 
    "__get()" exis``t and have public access in class 
    "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" ```

So it's not a problem of argument EM passed in the form EgwProjetSearchType : Symfony says "the entity doesnt exists"....

I dont have to pass EwgDispositif ?? It was not the cas in Symfony 2 : i had :

```
$formProjetSearch = $this->createForm(new EgwProjetSearchType($this-
```

> getDoctrine()->getManager()));

And this doesnt work anymore in 3.4.
So i changed the code :

```
$formProjetSearch = $this->createForm(EgwProjetSearchType::class, $em, [
'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
]);
```

Comment: The second argument to `createForm` expects the data to be handled (e.g. your entity [though beware best practices]), you're passing the entity manager, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: yes i want to pass em in arg like : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_dependencies.html

Comment: That's quite alright, just pass it in the options array, as you're already doing. `'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),`.

Comment: Again, you're passing `$em` as the second parameter to `createForm`. As per your code `$em` is the entity manager which obviously is not the form data! What you need is (for example), something like: `$this->createForm(EgwProjetSearchType::class, new EgwDispositif(), [
    'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
]);`

Comment: if you fixed the above issue with passing the entity manager as parameter and are now passing the actual entity instance there instead - you should also fix the form builder add to use "idDispositif" instead of "dispositif" (the addition should match your entity property).

Comment: you need a getter and setter method for dispositif

Answer (score 0):

In your entity you need to define your getters and setters. Your entity class is private so you must define public getters and setters to access the private objects.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: Thanks, but i have no EgwProjetSearch Entity.